# A question about to probability

Tags: probability

Fifteen boys and fifteen girls entered a drawing for four free movie tickets. What is the probability that all four tickets were won by girls

since no boys get movie tickets so pro =$\frac{\binom{15}{4}}{\binom{30}{4}}$  right?

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: For a counting argument to work, you need the outcomes to be equally likely, which is indeed the case here

Comment: This is correct assuming that each of the $\binom{30}{4}$ subsets of the aforementioned thirty boys and girls are equally likely to be the set of winners.  If the contest is run by one of the boy's friends and he cheats, only picking his friends to win, then the probability could be zero, or in the other extreme it could be $1$ or anywhere inbetween.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by the formula $p=\frac{\#\text{successful outcomes}}{\#\text{all outcomes}}.$

Comment: This needs a very strong disclaimer that the mentioned formula *only* works if each of the outcomes are equally likely to occur in the sample space.  There are only two possibilities when playing the lottery, you either win or you lose, but the probability of winning when playing most lotteries certainly is not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Of course. But when no additional information about the probability distribution is given, it's reasonable to assume (tacitly) that it's uniform. This is what I was thinking anyway.